# How to customize headers and footers?

Tags: packages, header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, scrpage2

I'd like to modify the contents of my headers and footers - e.g., to display the current chapter and/or section title or to change the pagination alignment. How can I do that? I've noticed the packages [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fancyhdr.html) and `scrpage2` (part of the [`KOMA-Script`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html)-bundle) - are they interchangeable, or are there situations where I should prefer one package to the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- `fancyhdr` is the classical package. The last change has been [Version 4.1 2022-11-09](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).
- `scrpage2` has been available for years but is also developing currently together with the modern `KOMA-script` classes. Naturally it is better integrated with those classes but it may be used with other classes as well.

`fancyhdr` provides a head rule and a foot rule, but `scrpage2` offers head top line, head separation line, foot separation line and foot bottom line.

`scrpage2` comes with a sophisticated interface to specify own styles, beginning with a simple `\deftripstyle` taking 9 parameters complemented by an expert interface: `\defpagestyle`, `\newpagestyle`, `\renewpagestyle` and `\providepagestyle`, see documentation.

To ease work with different styles `scrpage2` reads and processes a file `scrpage.cfg` where several styles for many projects might be defined.

So, I would prefer `scrpage2` if it's available. I'm sure it can replace `fancyhdr`. The latter package might be preferred if the requirements aren't too sophisticated and quick learning is expected.

Note: if you use `fancyhdr` and [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), [load geometry first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33874/geometry-fancyhdr-fancyfootc-thepage-is-not-really-centered).

Comment: scrpage2 also seems to be preferable for newcomers in a number of situations: Distinct elements of the pagestyles scrheadings and scrplain (the style for chapter start pages) can be changed with one command (using its optional argument for scrplain), and differentiating between left and right pages is also easier. One feature of fancyhdr not included in scrpage2 is distinct headers and footers for pages containg only floats.

Comment: True. The float support comes mainly by `\iffloatpage`, a one-liner that might be used with scrpage2 as well: `\providecommand{\iffloatpage}[2]{\if@fcolmade #1\else #2\fi}`.

Comment: What about "[From KOMA-Script 3.12 the completely newly implemented package `scrlayer-scrpage` replaces the old `scrpage2`](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrpage2.pdf)"?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Could this answer be updated to reference the [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) instead of `scrpage2`?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz What Werner said.

Answer (score 14):

Since November 2011, there's a third package dedicated to customizing headers and footers: [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) by Javier Bezos (the author of `enumitem`, `titlesec`, and `titletoc`). Package description:

> The package provides page styles with a simple one-stage mechanism,
>   including top marks; access to top-, first- and botmarks in a single
>   header/footer; headers/footers for specific floats; multiple sets of
>   marks (with e-TeX), and more.

Note that the features listed in `titleps`' description aren't available in `fancyhdr` and `scrpage2`.