# Header, footer and font customization

Tags: header-footer

How can I create a default header, footer and customize the font of my LaTeX document?

I wanted something like this:

```
Default book title                     Chapter name
____________________________________________________________

content

____________________________________________________________
www.defaulturl.com                     PAGE NUMBER
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! There's a lot of questions/answers about customizing headers and footers at our site; for starters, have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-to-customize-head-and-footlines) question and browse the {header-footer} tag.

Comment: Also, the [the Page Layout section of the LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_styles) should help you.

Comment: also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99215/how-do-you-right-justify-page-numbers-and-get-them-in-the-header/99678#99678

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in Stefan's answer to [How to customize headers and footers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1247/3954), `fancyhdr` is the classical package to customize headers/footers. However, recently I've been using the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to define page styles, and I've found it really useful and as powerful as `fancyhdr`, so here's a little example achieving the desired result with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some filler text

\newcommand*\defaulturl{\url{www.some-url.com}}
\newcommand*\defaulttitle{Some Title}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead{\defaulttitle}{}{\chaptertitle}\headrule
  \setfoot{\defaulturl}{}{\thepage}\footrule
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Gonzalo mentioned [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) (the classic solution) and [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). Modern classes such as [Koma-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html) classes (`scrbook` and friends) and `memoir` also have built-in ways of achieving this.

In the case of Koma-Script classes for example, you can achieve a lot by using the `scrpage2` package. *(Update 2014:)* Since version 3.12 you should use the successor package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead.

Comment: Actually, `scrpage2` can be used with the standard classes as well.

Comment: @lockstep: good to know. I've only seen it used in Koma, and `fancyhdr` used in most cases.