# Header and Footer

Tags: header-footer, color, page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Header, footer and font customization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20109/header-footer-and-font-customization)

I am writing on a larger project (a book) and I now there are lots of possibilities about headers. But I am a newbie and I do not know which is perhaps the best, so I wanted to ask you how I should implement a header in the best way? I want the header to display the page number and the section title and also there should be a line under it. I do not know how to implement this, also the page number which is now under the text should disappear and the text in the header should have a color, but the page number should be black. The line should be a little more than maybe 4 pt thick. Thanks a lot for your help! 
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=4cm,right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
%,bookmarksopenlevel={1}
%\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,bookmarksopen=false,
hypertexnames=TRUE,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}[2011/02/05]
\hypersetup{ 
  pdftitle={},
%  pdfauthor={},
  pdfsubject={Statistics Book}, 
  pdfkeywords={}, 
  }
\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{makeidx}        
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{ulem}

\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{rgb}{.9,.9,.95}%

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%

\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=shadethmcolor,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{example}{example}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.1cm}
\marginparsep = -4pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\include{dedic}
\newpage\section*{} 
\include{foreword}
\newpage\section*{} 
\include{preface}
\newpage\section*{} 
\include{acknow}
\newpage\section*{} 
\include{acronym}
%
    \shorttableofcontents{Inhalts\"ubersicht}{1}
\bookmark[page=15,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},color=red]{Inhalts\"ubersicht}
\bookmark[page=17,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},color=red]{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
%



\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{part1} 
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{part2}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\backmatter

\appendix 

\include{appendix}

\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\backmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\include{glossary}
%\include{solutions}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Index}
\printindex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\"Uber den Autor}
\includepdf{ueberautor}
\includepdf{back}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you seem to be using the titlesec package already, the `\newpagestyle` command should fit your needs (you also need to provide the option `pagestyles` when loading the titlesec package). The titlesec manual explains how to use it with nice examples (see in particular page 12).

Comment: mh, that does not help me, because I also do not know what to do with \newpagestyle?

Comment: Ok, I have just given a more detailed answer. Still, it may be worth reading the titlesec manual to get more information on how to use these commands and examples of what they can do.

Comment: Note also that there are other book classes that include such functionalities, such as `memoir` and `scrbook`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to replace the line

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

with

```
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
```

to make the command `\newpagestyle` available. Then you can create your own header and footer style with this command with the syntax: `\newpagestyle{stylename}[global style options]{commands}`. The "commands" argument may include other commands such as `\headrule` to include an horizontal line under the header (as you seem to wish) or `\sethead` to customize the contents of the headers. The syntax is `\sethead[even-left][even-center][even-right]{odd-left}{odd-center}{odd-right}`.

For instance, you can create the style "mystyle" by adding the following lines:

```
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
\headrule \sethead[\thepage][][\color{red} \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle]
{\color{red} \thesection\ \sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
```

If you are only interested in the section title and not the chapter (although you are using the book class), you can try

```
\newpagestyle{mystyle2}{
\headrule \sethead[\thepage][][\color{red} \thesection\ \sectiontitle]
{\color{red} \thesection\ \sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle2}
```

This should look like what you are expecting.

Comment: mh, it does not work, I get the error message ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package titlesec.

Comment: ok, now it does work. But I also want to have the line under it more thicker and colored and also the page number colored, how can I do this?

Comment: If you want the page number to be colored also, you can move the `\color{red}` out of the `\sethead` command and put it in the global style options in the `\newpagestyle` command.

Comment: and how can I get the line under it more thicker and colored? Thanks

Comment: About the color, my previous comment does not seem to work for the headrule, but regarding the thickness, you can simply add a `\setheadrule{length}` command (the default length being .4pt).