# How do you Right-Justify Page Numbers and get them in the header?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

When I made PDFs with Texmaker the page numbers are by default at the bottom of the page (i.e. in the footer) and are centred. How do I change this?

Comment: the fancyhdr package can arrange this for you.  someone may even tell you how, if you provide a minimal example that can be patched for instructional purposes.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20109/header-footer-and-font-customization as well

Answer (score 2):

depending on the document class you're using, you might not even need fancyhdr (Which is why a minimal example would be useful, so we know ›where‹ you are). For example, the `komascript` bundle comes with the `scrpage2` package, which, however, also works with other classes as well. Here's what I use, except I put them in the footer rather than the header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} % or article, etc.
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot %clears headers + footers
\ohead{\thepage\hspace*{3em}} %sets new header
\begin{document}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

See also »adapting page headers and footers« [in scrguien.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned, you could use the [fancyhdr package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). It is more complicated, but I use it for everything anyway, because it is so robust. A couple things to note:

1. I use xelatex
2. I use fancyhdr in conjunction with geometry (notice the options includefoot and includehead: These keep the header and footer within margins, but if you check out the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry), you can find all kinds of settings.

The main thing you want to look at is **\rhead{\thepage}**

\thepage is the page number variable (counter)

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%SET MARGINS (AND PAGE DIMENSIONS)
\usepackage[includefoot,includehead,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
%HEADER FOOTER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{\thepage} %sets header left center right
\lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{} %sets footer left center right
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} %optional horizontal rule thickness
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt} %optional horizontal rule thickness
\pagestyle{fancy}%ADD HEADER FOOTER TO PAGE EXCEPT TITLE PAGE %ensure fancyhdr is applied to doc
%USE \thispagestyle{EMPTY} BELOW MAKETITLE IF YOU USE IT OR \thispagestyle{FANCY}

\begin{document}
Test Document
\end{document}
```

Another thing to note. If you are using the article class and you use a \maketitle command, by default, the first page will not have the header/footer from fancyhdr, but will have the default page number. To deal with this, use

- \thispagestyle{empty} % disable header/footer
- \thispagestyle{fancy} % apply fancyhdr header/footer

Let us assume you want the title page to have no header/footer. You will run into another problem, namely that the page number counter still starts with the title page, but you want page 1 to be the first page with content. To solve this, just put a

- \setcounter{page}{1} % sets the counter to value

on whichever page you want to be page 1.