# geometry, fancyhdr: \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} is not really centered

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, incompatibility, geometry

After switching from the `report` class to the `book` class and starting to use the `fancyhdr` package to control headers/footers, the page numbers in my footers are no longer centered.

This is my `fancyhdr` setup:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
%activate the style:
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} %paper format
\geometry{left=27.5mm,right=27.5mm,bottom=27.5mm,top=27.5mm} %margins
```

With this the page numbers are placed off-center. On even pages they are to the right of the center and on odd ones they are to the left of it. What I want is a perfectly centered (with respect to the page) pagenumber in the footer of even and odd pages alike (like it was when I used the `report` class and no `fancyhdr`s).

Comment: The setup for **fancyhdr** is not sufficient to make a diagnosis; are you also changing the parameters for page building?

Comment: I'm not sure which parameters you mean?

Comment: If I use that code, the page number goes at the desired place. Do you have some setting to `\textwidth` or `\evensidemargin`?

Comment: It's centered in relation to the text, not to the page. You may notice it in twosided layout, when inner and outer margins are different. I suggest keeping centering to the text body, just imagine a full page and the page number below.

Comment: It's not centered to the page, nor the text here. I will add my page (paper) setup to the question, maybe this is relevant?

Comment: The best and most relevant is a compilable minimal example. You could edit your question adding the minimally necessary lines (class, relevant preamble entries, ..)

Comment: I use a long list of packages and customisations, grouped in a custom class that derives from book. I'm trying to create a MWE that is based on book alone (+ fancyhdr & geometry) but so far I'm not able to reproduce the problem I get with my class. Any ideas which other packages could cause this problem? Or would it be ok if I just upload my class file somewhere? (It's a bit big to post inline)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution is to load `geometry` before `fancyhdr` and apply the settings, then configure `fancyhdr`, not the other way round.

A working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} %paper format
\geometry{left=27.5mm,right=27.5mm,bottom=27.5mm,top=27.5mm} %margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
%activate the style:
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering\thepage
\end{document}
```

In this example, if `\usepackage{geometry}` and the `\geometry` settings are moved below `\pagestyle{plain}`, the undesired behavior occurs. I wonder why `geometry` is not even mentioned in the `fancyhdr` manual, when I see this dependency.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! In fact, I had *just* figured it out myself while assembling a proper MWE.

Comment: @Matthias: That's the great benefit of MWEs, they're basically like debugging `:)`. Have you considered contacting the author of `fancyhdr` and asking him if this "conflict" should go into the manual?

Answer (score 0):

It happens I redefined a geometry because the document requires it. So my headrule, fancyfoot and everything was not working really well.

```tex
\fancypagestyle{custom-fancy}{%
    \newgeometry{
        top=25mm,
        left=30mm,
        right=30mm,
        bottom=25mm,
        includeheadfoot
    }
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{Just a title}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it overflows and I read in the documentation it was because all the head and foot commands were defined by `\headwidth`

> \headwidth is a length parameter that defines the total width of the headers and footers.

But it is weird, because the package documentation says

[image]

So the most practical solution I found was to redefine this value just adding `\setlength{\headwidth}{\linewidth}` to my fancy style. And voalá.

```tex
\fancypagestyle{custom-fancy}{%
    \newgeometry{
        top=25mm,
        left=30mm,
        right=30mm,
        bottom=25mm,
        includeheadfoot
    }
    \fancyhf{}
    \setlength{\headwidth}{\linewidth}
    \fancyhead[C]{Just a title}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}
```

[image]