# Page layout for two-sided document

Tags: margins, double-sided

In the minimal example pasted below I would like to have:

- left margin on even pages = 1.5cm
- right margin on odd pages = 1.5cm

(understood as absolute values, not added to/substracted from default settings)

How do I have to set `\oddsidemargin`, `\evensidemargin` and/or `\hoffset`?

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\voffset=-1.5cm
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{45\baselineskip}
\setlength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
% hoffset, oddsidemargins, evensidemargins = ???
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: fancyhdr added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[
  textwidth=16.5cm,
  outer=1.5cm,
  textheight=45\baselineskip,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  includehead=false,% Default
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\section{foobar}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: **Question**: Are there any implications of this package for the rest of the document? Does the geometry package interfere with other packages, e.g. fancyhdr? see edited original post!

Comment: @lpdbw: `geometry` is a very mature, de-facto standard package. If you use `fancyhdr`, load it after `geometry` -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33874/geometry-fancyhdr-fancyfootc-thepage-is-not-really-centered

Comment: If I add the header from my original post (note: it was edited!) to your code (after geometry) I get an error.

Comment: @lpdbw You forgot to load `fancyhdr`, plus there's a (unknown to me) `\truncate` macro. I edited my MWE (which works for me).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, was my fault! What does includehead=false mean? Does the top margin become slightly bigger if I change it to includehead=true? I tried it but the difference (if any) seems to be minimal ...

Comment: @lpdbw `includehead=false` means that the header is not included when calculating the `textheight`. As you specify `textheight` absolute (as a multiple of `\baselineskip`), the remaining difference is about vertically aligning the text block on the page.