# Help with footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm pretty much finished the document I'm working on, but now that I'm adding the footer I have run into some issues. I'm using `fancyhdr` and have rather small margin, so the footer doesn't really fit atm. It's also not in the center of the page and I've got a strange line at the top that I don't know where it's coming from. I realize that I will probably have to adjust my margins a bit, but I need to keep them as close as possible to current as I am matching the style of a previous document and have some large flowcharts.

[image: footer]

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%% Packages and configuration %%%%%
\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark} % watermark
\SetWatermarkText{\textsc{Confidential}}
\SetWatermarkScale{4}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.9}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
%\fancyfoot[LE,CO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
%\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Message of the day} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\lfoot{Lorem\\Ipsum}\cfoot{dolor sit\\amet \\ \thepage}\rfoot{Rev. \#\\ \today}



\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} % Advanced page geometry configuation
%\usepackage[cm]{fullpage} % Alternate option for page configuration
%\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.7in, bottom=0.9in, left=0.7in, right=0.7in, showframe]{geometry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should load [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) *after* [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: Perhaps, with `geometry`'s `includefoot` option?

Comment: See [`\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` is not really centered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874/5764)...

Comment: @Werner, your first suggestion worked. Any ideas on the line at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's 2 issues with the top rule: 1. It is there because `fancyhdr` has it by default and 2. it's not centered because you loaded `geometry` after `fancyhdr`. As suggested by Peter Grill, a `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}` will remove it.

The footer has no room for text: You have .5in (36pt) margins and 30pt of `\footsep`. That means the bottom of the textblock will be 36 points above the bottom of the paper, and that the footer text will be bottom aligned at 30pt below the textblock (6pt above the paper limit). If your text is 10pt high, it will need around 24pt (for the leading usually is 120% the font size); if it's 12pt, it will need 28pt *at least*.

You can solve it either by increasing the bottom margin:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

Or by including the footer in the textblock, by using `includefoot` option:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,includefoot]{geometry}
```

Here are two MWE:

#### With `bottom=1in`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,bottom=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}% To remove the rule on the top of the page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\lfoot{Lorem\\Ipsum}\cfoot{dolor sit\\amet \\ \thepage}\rfoot{Rev. \#\\ \today}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: With bottom=1in]

#### With `includefoot`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,includefoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}% To remove the rule on the top of the page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\lfoot{Lorem\\Ipsum}\cfoot{dolor sit\\amet \\ \thepage}\rfoot{Rev. \#\\ \today}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A similar result could be obtained with option `footskip=4mm` for example (of course always before of footer definition)

Comment: I used the `includefoot` option. Thanks for the help!