# Fancyhdr line is too short: How to make it longer?

Tags: fancyhdr

How can I make the headerline longer?

At the moment it looks like this:
[image]

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{section one}
test text blablah long text long text long text long text long texttest text blablah long text long text long text long text long text

\end{document}
```

You can see it also here:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/bqsfbwrbpmyn

Comment: It's not really possible to comment on such a small fragment, please fix the question to have a complete minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: There is one if you follow the link.

Comment: @texNewFag that's far from minimal, and AFAICT we can only see that one file (_not_ where the header is set up) without signing up for an account.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: edited my question

Comment: @texNewFag please review [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/21344).

Comment: @PaulGessler now I have a minimal example :-)

Comment: @texNewFag: You have to load [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) *before* [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

Comment: Thanks! You can solve the problem by moving the setting of the margins (`\usepackage[...]{geometry}`) to before the header setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`geometry`, `fancyhdr`: `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` is not really centered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874/5764)