# Page number misplaced using fancyhdr, custom color and "includefoot" geometry-option

Tags: header-footer, color, fancyhdr, geometry

If I color the page number with the packages `fancyhdr` and `xcolor`, I get the page number out of the space defined as "footskip" in the `geometry` package.

I am enclosing a MWE where you can see that if the page number is colored with `\color{customcolor}`, it gets misplaced (it is below the line drawn by `geometry`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\geometry{bottom=30pt,includeheadfoot, showframe}

\definecolor{customcolor}{RGB}{112,112,112}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\color{customcolor}\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

Hello!  

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid it?

(I am compiling this on LuaTeX)

Comment: Use `\fancyfoot[CO]{\textcolor{customcolor}{\thepage}}`.

Comment: You should load [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fanychdr) *after* loading/setting your [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry). See [`geometry`, `fancyhdr`: `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` is not really centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874/5764)

Comment: @Werner I got the same mistake in another file where I inverted the packages loading order, but thanks anyway for pointing that issue out.

Comment: @Bernard it works perfectly, thanks! Could you please explain me why in this context there is this difference between `\color{.}` and `\textcolor{.}`? 
By the way, would you write your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I have no  idea why there's a difference. I tested just in case… But I hac=ve a simpler solution with `titleps` that I'll add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using \fancyfoot[CO]{\textcolor{customcolor}{\thepage}}` solves the problem.

However, the `titleps` package, used in the place of `fncyhdr` doesn't have this drawback, and has a simpler syntax, with the `\renewpagestyle{plain}{...}` command:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{customcolor}{RGB}{112,112,112}

 \usepackage{titleps}
 \renewpagestyle{plain}{%
 \setfoot{}{\color{customcolor}{\thepage}}{}
 }%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bottom=30pt,includeheadfoot, showframe}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

Hello!

\end{document}
```

[image]