# Adjustment of header and footer

Tags: header-footer, alignment

I have adjusted my text, so it's like an A4-paper. But my header and footer have not aligned. In my preamble I've got:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

And in my main script I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{z.preamble/preamble.tex}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
```

It looks like this in the pdf:
[image]

PS: don't mind the weird letters, it's just an example, so you can see it, thank you.

Comment: Load the `geometry` package before the packages which modify your header, i.e. before `fancyhdr`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: don't load the same packages multiple times and don't load the `times` package, it is obsolete

Comment: That helped, thank you. Do you know which package I should then use if I want the font Times New Roman?

Comment: See http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l2tabu-english/l2tabuen.pdf section 2.3.1 for different possible replacements

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [geometry, fancyhdr: \fancyfoot\[C\]{\thepage} is not really centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33874/geometry-fancyhdr-fancyfootc-thepage-is-not-really-centered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As samcarter wrote in comments: "Load the `geometry` package before the packages which modify your header, i.e. before `fancyhdr`"