# How do I align page number in the footer in the center?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using the following to insert page numbers in my footer:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

However, it is inserting them a little bit left-aligned and not in the perfect center of the page like this:

[image]

How do I align things properly?

Comment: `\fancyfoot{C}{\thepage}` should do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Did you change the page geometry after loading fancyhdr?  Once created, fancyhdr never changes the width.  You can however fake it using \makebox.

Comment: This question may be helpful: [geometry, fancyhdr: \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} is not really centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874)