# chapter title long and necessity to cut it

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, line-breaking, chapters

my chapter title is too long and I have the necessity to cut it in two different lines. well which could be the best way to cut it?I tried using `\newline` but unfortunately this modification affects also title page in every page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sectioning commands like `\chapter` feature an optional argument that will be used in the header/footer and the table of contents. So use the optional argument of `\chapter` and omit the line break there.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter[A very long chapter title]{A very long \\chapter title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is a way to change font dimension to text usend in optional part of chapter code?. for instance: `A very long chapter title`can  become small?

Comment: @Mazzy There are different ways - preferably you'd use a package like `scrpage2` to customize the appearance of the header/footer. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-to-customize-head-and-footlines