# Configure page heading in book class

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my thesis and I have a trouble formatting the heading.

The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}  

Citation here

\newpage

Bla bla

\chapter*{Conclusion}  

\end{document}
```

My output heading looks like this:
[image]

But I need this, i.e. with such a font setup and an under rule:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for giving a minimal example document. Surely your supervisor's name is not really relevant to the question, though, so you might want to remove that (and also from your other question). There are various methods for doing headers and footers. See [How to customize headers and footers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1250/2693) and for some specific examples see [Headers and footers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87768/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn It is also misleading. I assumed that was some thesis template or template guru, of which I knew nowt.

Comment: Have you considered using KOMA book, since you like `typearea`?

Comment: How can I keep the header in the Chapeter 1 Introduction page??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an option with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % To clear page numbers from footer, and header line at the start of every chapter

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}  
    \lipsum[1-15]
    \chapter{Introduction}  
    \lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image: f]

[image: s]